# Javascript equivalent to $('body')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a javascript equivalent to the jQuery `$('body')`, as in the following code? I want to get it running without requiring jQuery.

```
var content = $('body').html();
var comments = content.match(/<!--.*?-->/g);
if(comments!=null|comments!=undefined){
    for (var x = 0; x < comments.length;x++){
        console.log(comments[x]);
    }
}
else{
    console.log('No Comments');
}
```

Thanks

https://gist.github.com/hughrawlinson/6078055

Comment: I think `document.body` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is `document.body`

```
 var contents = document.body.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `$('body').html()` with:

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in comments.

```
var contents = document.body.innerHTML;
```

or

```
var contents = document.getElementsByTagName('body').innerHTML;
```

Comment: The first one will not give the contents right ? It ll just give a reference to the body tag.